# Clean up ncurses mess in terminal after a crash

Tags: terminal, ncurses

I am drawing a TUI using ncurses. The trouble is that whenever my program gets seg-fault, my terminal is left in mess. I can not see what I am typing. Its a pain since I am working over ssh. I have mitigated some of the effect by using screen.

I would like to know if there is a command which will refresh my terminal after seg-fault in ncurses so that my terminal starts behaving normally.

Comment: Most terminal programs have a "reset" option which puts the terminal back into its initial state - useful for situations like this - check the menus in your program.

Comment: @PaulR I am using gnome-terminal. Reset doesn't do the job ;-(

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Command `stty sane` did the job. If enter doesn't work, you may use `^J`.

```
stty sane ^J
```

Sometimes CR/LF interpretation is broken so use the `^J` explicitly.

Comment: I still do not see the cursor.

Comment: suggest writting the control J as below comment Thomas Dickey

Comment: scroll now instead goes to a different command in history instead of scrolling up and down in terminal view

Comment: The comment about "older terminal" is incorrect.

Comment: You saved me, thanks a lot @Dilawar

Answer (score 18):

ncurses (any curses implementation) sets the terminal modes to *raw* and *noecho* while running, and allows applications to simulate these using the [raw and noraw](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-raw_noraw), [echo and noecho](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-echo_noecho) functions.  It does this for performance, to avoid waiting when switching between these modes.

When an application calls [`endwin`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-endwin), ncurses restores the terminal modes.  It can also do this for [reset_shell_mode](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html#h3-reset_prog_mode_-reset_shell_mode), though `endwin` is used far more often.

If your application crashes, or exits without restoring the terminal modes using `endwin`, the most obvious problem is that you cannot see what you are typing, and that pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> does not work.

ncurses provides a signal handler to catch the user-initiated signals `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, and will cleanup when *those* are caught.  It does not try to catch `SIGSEGV` because at that point, your application is dead and trying to resurrect it to repair things is counter productive.

Some people might advise using `stty sane` to restore the terminal modes.  That "works", but on Unix platforms is likely to leave your *erase* key set to an unexpected value.  It happens to work as expected for Linux- and modern BSD-systems.

However, beyond that, ncurses normally resets

- colors (default colors for the terminal)
- line-drawing (disabled)
- mouse protocol (to disable it)

If your application uses any of these features, then the `reset` command is the appropriate choice.  It usually clears the screen as well (perhaps not what was wanted).  And it uses fewer characters:

`reset`<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
   `stty sane`<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

Further reading:

- [Signal handlers](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers) in *curs_initscr(3x)*
- [Portability](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html#h2-PORTABILITY) in *tput(1)*
- [**`reset`** *- reinitialization*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h3-reset---reinitialization)

Answer (score 7):

The command

```
reset
```

also worked for me on Ubuntu, probably overkill though.
What worked best was setting an alias like:

```
alias 'clean'='stty sane;clear;'
```

in my .bash_aliases as I found myself needing to do this alot in debugging.

Comment: I still do not see the cursor.

Comment: The reset command "should" do this, as a side-effect of the initialization strings it sends. The terminal description may not do that, but **`tput cnorm`** is more explicit and more likely to work.

Answer (score 4):

Write a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`, etc. that calls `endwin()`.

Comment: Here is how to do it (only be sure to handle SIGSEGV and not SIGTERM): http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/ncurses-dev-254581-print/

Comment: That won't work (will actually aggravate the situation).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently on a Mac OSX terminal. Following set of commands worked whereas stty sane did not.

```
stty discard '^O'
stty dsusp '^Y'
stty eof '^D'
stty eol '^@'
stty eol2 '^@'
stty erase '^?'
stty intr '^C'
stty kill '^U'
stty lnext '^V'
stty min 1
stty quit '^\'
stty reprint '^R'
stty start '^Q'
stty status '^T'
stty stop '^S'
stty susp '^Z'
stty time 0
stty werase '^W'
```