# Use curses to detect user input immediately

Tags: python, python-2.7, curses

I'm using curses in python2.7 to control a robot. I would like to steer it with e.g. the `w` key, to tell it it should go forward. Here's my code, stripped away of all robot controls:

```
import curses
from time import sleep

if __name__ == "__main__":
    shell = curses.initscr()
    shell.nodelay(True)

    while True:
        key = shell.getch()

        if key == 119:
            print("key w pressed")

        sleep(0.03)
```

That works fine, except that I have to press enter for the key to be recognized. So I can press `w` several times, and when I press enter, the robot does exactly what it's supposed to do, or in this example, the text `key w pressed` appears as many times as I have pressed it. But I would like this to happen immediately, i.e. without having to press enter. How can this be achieved?

Comment: add `curses.cbreak()` to your setup.

Comment: This helps, thanks. It does also break my shell, but I guess I can figure out myself how to fix that. If you elevate this comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `curses.cbreak()` to your setup, and when you cleanup call `curses.nocbreak()` to restore the terminal to a usable state.

You can do the cleanup by catching <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> as an exception. Eg:

```
 try:
     curses.cbreak()
     while True:
            key = shell.getch()
            if key == 119:
                print("key w pressed")
            sleep(0.03)
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
     curses.nocbreak()
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that OP did not use [window.keypad](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.keypad), calling either [curses.raw](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.raw) or [curses.cbreak](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.cbreak) would give (almost) the same result for allowing the script to read unbuffered characters.

Calling [`curses.endwin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.endwin) is a more reliable way to restore things. Bear in mind that it is a wrapper around curses.  curses *simulates* cbreak mode, setting the real terminal mode to *raw*.  Calling [`curses.nocbreak`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.nocbreak) has *no* effect on the real terminal mode.

If you call `nocbreak` to cleanup rather than call `endwin`, you will have additional problems to resolve (see [Clean up ncurses mess in terminal after a crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753909/clean-up-ncurses-mess-in-terminal-after-a-crash) for instance), because the terminal will be in raw mode (including real `noecho`, which makes typing `stty sane^M` painful).

Referring to the documentation for [`endwin`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-endwin),

> A  program should always call **endwin** before exiting or escaping from curses mode temporarily.  This routine

```
   o   restores tty modes,

   o   moves the cursor to the lower left-hand corner of  the
       screen and

   o   resets the terminal into the proper non-visual mode.
```

As noted, `cbreak` and `raw` are *almost* the same.  The main difference lies in how the program would respond to keyboard interrupts (things like `^C`).  If you happen to be using ncurses, it establishes [signal handlers](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers) which (for `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM`) will call `curses.endwin`.  Other curses implementations do not do this, and even if your script calls `curses.endwin` it is not certain that it will work as intended (since curses tends to call unsafe stream I/O functions which cannot be used reliably in a signal handler).

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are correct, `cbreak()` will switch off buffered input mode, meaning `getch()` will return a key press immediately.

I suggest using the `curses.wrapper()` function. This sets up the screen, and buffering, how you want it in this case. But it also catches exceptions and makes sure the terminal is returned to a clean state when your application exits. Read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html#starting-and-ending-a-curses-application)

An example based on the OPs code would be:

```
import curses
from time import sleep

def program_loop(stdscr):
    while True:
        key = stdscr.getch()


        if key == 119:
            print("key w pressed\r")

        sleep(0.03)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(program_loop)
```