# How not to mess terminal up after sys.stdin.read() and subprocess invoking vim?

Tags: python, pipe, command-line-interface, stdin, io-redirection

I want to create interactive mode code like `git rebase -i HEAD~6` but for PIPE editing, stdin redirection. another example is [vipe](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) of `moreutils`.

To do that, I learn this code below.

```py
# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39989442/20307768
import sys, tempfile, os
from subprocess import call

EDITOR = os.environ.get('EDITOR', 'vim')  # that easy!

initial_message = b'something'  # if you want to set up the file somehow

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".tmp") as tf: 
  tf.write(initial_message)
  tf.flush()
  call([EDITOR, tf.name])
```

**To get PIPE and edit it, I added two lines.**

```py
text = sys.stdin.read()
initial_message = text.encode()
```

**The problematic full code** is below.

```py
import sys, tempfile, os
from subprocess import call

EDITOR = os.environ.get('EDITOR', 'vim')

text = sys.stdin.read()
initial_message = text.encode()

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".tmp") as tf: 
    tf.write(initial_message)
    tf.flush()
    call([EDITOR, tf.name])
```

After running the second code with `echo "some words" | python the_code.py` in the shell and exiting vim`:q!`, the terminal is messed up. (`reset` in the shell command will fix it.)

Without `reset`, I can type in a shell of macOS, but the prompt is in a weird place.
I can't even type in a shell of Linux.

*I typed `set -x`, already.*

```bash
[rockyos@localhost python-vipe]$ echo "asdfasd" | python vipe.py
+ python vipe.py
+ echo asdfasd
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
++ printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' rockyos localhost '~/TODO/python-vipe'
                                                                            ++ history -a
                                                                                         ++ history -c
                                                                                                      ++ history -r
                                                                                                                   [rockyos@localhost python-vipe]$
```

I just want to return normal terminal after running the second full code.
Also, why is this happening?

I tried `os.system('stty sane; clear;')` and `os.system('reset')` at the end of the code.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/17452756/20307768)  `os.system('reset')` gave me what I wanted. But the message is annoying. I mean I can do `os.system('clear')` again, but that is not what normal other program does.

```
Erase set to delete. 
Kill set to control-U (^U). 
Interrupt set to control-C (^C).
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 22, your full code works.

Comment: @GibezynuNu, type something in the shell after running the code. In Rocky and macOS, It is weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create interactive mode code like git rebase -i HEAD~6 but for PIPE editing, stdin redirection. another example is vipe of moreutils.

vipe is an open-source tool, and the [source code](https://github.com/stigtsp/moreutils/blob/master/vipe) is less than 100 lines long, so let's take a moment to look at how it does this. It can't rely on stdin or stdout to be a terminal, because normally it's used in the middle of a series of pipes.

Here's how they solved that, in Perl. First, they close STDIN, or file descriptor 0. Then, they open `/dev/tty` in read mode at descriptor 0. They also do the same thing for STDOUT, but we don't need that.

```perl
close STDIN;
open(STDIN, "</dev/tty") || die "reopen stdin: $!";
open(OUT, ">&STDOUT") || die "save stdout: $!";
close STDOUT;
open(STDOUT, ">/dev/tty") || die "reopen stdout: $!";
```

So, how can we do the same thing in Python?

1. Open `/dev/tty` in read mode.
2. That might not have been opened at descriptor 0, so copy it to descriptor 0.
3. Close the old FD.

Code:

```
import sys, tempfile, os
from subprocess import check_call

EDITOR = os.environ.get('EDITOR', 'vim')

text = sys.stdin.read()
initial_message = text.encode()

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".tmp") as tf: 
    tf.write(initial_message)
    tf.flush()

    stdin_fd = os.open('/dev/tty', os.O_RDONLY)
    os.dup2(stdin_fd, 0)
    os.close(stdin_fd)

    check_call([EDITOR, tf.name])

    print(open(tf.name).read())
```

This was tested on OSX 13.3.1.

Comment: I just tested it in rocky os. It works. Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: I actually never thought to make a [Python port](https://github.com/Constantin1489/pyvipe#thanks-to) of `vipe` before your answer, I made it. Thank you. The specific script file is [here](https://github.com/Constantin1489/pyvipe/blob/master/pyvipe/pyvipe.py).